# fetchPypi doesn't fetch the right url to load a .whl file to build a package

Tags: python, nix, nix-flake

I ve followed these [instructions](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Packaging/Python)  (paragraph : build from source):

```
{
  description = "virtual environment with python and streamlit";
  inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
  inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
        python=pkgs.python311;

    xTuring = pkgs.python3Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "xTuring";
      version = "v0.1.6";
      format = "wheel";

    src = pkgs.python3Packages.fetchPypi rec {
        inherit pname version format;
        sha256 = "a9e78c46b807f3a14f567e151feaed993085dad601a5b5826db258afd8699914"; 
        dist = python;
        python = "py3";
        #abi = "none";
        #platform = "any";
      };

      #propagatedBuildInputs = with python; [ setproctitle ];
    };

        
        f = ps: with ps;[
          ipython
          matplotlib
          pandas

        ];        
        pip_python_packages= python.withPackages(f);

        myDevTools = [
          pip_python_packages
          pkgs.streamlit
          xTuring
        ];
      in rec {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = myDevTools;
        };
      });
}
```

error message:

> trying
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/py3/x/xTuring/xTuring-v0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl
> blabla
> fails

It is normal [the package page](https://pypi.org/project/xturing/#files) says that the url should be  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/c5/f38749c4f5121fdd79e669f0e39d8c5f03949cbcc57ff4ffc8f4d56a0dcc/xturing-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl
instead of

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/py3/x/xTuring/xTuring-v0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl

I've followed the instructions why fetchPypi  doesn't fetch the right URL

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises from the fact that (1) the package name should be `xturing` rather than `xTuring` (capitalization), and (2) the version should be `0.1.6` instead of `v0.1.6`. As shown in the PyPi URL:

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/c5.../xturing-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl

There are no capital letters in the file name, nor is there a "v" preceding the version number.

Hence you should correct your source fetching parameters to

```hs
pname = "xturing";
version = "0.1.6";
format = "wheel";
src = pkgs.python3Packages.fetchPypi rec {
  inherit pname version format;
  sha256 = pkgs.lib.fakeSha256;
  dist = python;
  python = "py3";
};
```